# Caret '^' Function Pointers in C99

Tags: c, pointers

GCC's stdlib.h on OSX has the following function prototype

```
int heapsort_b(void *__base, size_t __nel, size_t __width,
     int (^ _Nonnull __compar)(const void *, const void *))
```

I know that `_Nonnull` is some internal OSX thingie. But what about this '^'? Is it safe to just treat is as `*`?

Comment: This is objective-C code.

Comment: Yet it expanded while compiling a .c file, not .m file. I.e. GCC apparently supports lambdas. Is it possible to enable them in vanila GCC for Windows and BSD?

Comment: You'd need Apple's extensions (which should be available somwehere), but they're apparently not part of any standard gcc version.

Comment: "Apple's gcc-4.2.1 implementation for blocks was not actually submitted (and therefore doesn't exist on an FSF server);  it's my understanding that means we cannot use / forward port it."